# Accessing the Property of Javascript object failing

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function that needs to have object as its parameter. I want to get the property and values of the object. Following is the list of JS object in my program:

```
var a =[{'Jan':1555},{'Feb':456},{'Mar':987},{'Apr':768}];
```

As expected to get the property and values one can use for loop here like below:

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
for(var j in a[i]){
    console.log(j);        // Here it returns the property correctly
    console.log(a[i].j);  //Returns Error here ie returns undefined
     }
}
```

Now above line **console.log(a[i].j)** returns **undefined** values while if manually checking the list like **a[0].Jan** I get **1555** , **a[1].Feb** returns **456** and so on.
Why is this so? Please correct the code if I am wrong as i am new in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access it with `console.log(a[i][j]);`

Accessing it with `a[i].j` is like accessing it with `a[i]["j"]`, which isn't what you want. Also, whenever you use `for ... in`, you should always check it with `obj.hasOwnProperty`

Use this code instead

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(var j in a[i]){
        if(a[i].hasOwnProperty(j){
            console.log(j);        // Here it returns the property correctly
            console.log(a[i][j]);  
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.j` property doesn't exist, You should do it like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(var j in a[i]){
        console.log(j);        // Here it returns the property correctly
        console.log(a[i][j]);  //Now works
     }
}
```

However, I'd write it as the following to be more understandable:

```
for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++){
    var item = a[i];
    for(var month in item){
        console.log("month: ", month);        
        console.log("value: ", item[month]);
     }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks for the info. I checked that property can be accessed using . which i applied here. Thanks for clarification.